# Clipping views with PathGeometry in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to clip a StackLayout with the following path, but it clips nothing in the window:
GaugeView.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Xamarin.Forms.GaugeView.GaugeView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout.Clip>
                <PathGeometry
                    Figures="M0,150A300,300 0 1,1 300,150L220,150A300,300 0 1,1 80,150Z"/>
            </StackLayout.Clip>
            <Label
                Text="Hello clip"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Xamarin.Forms.GaugeView.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GaugeView">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:GaugeView
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    HeightRequest="100"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

[image: clip nothing]

What am I do wrong?

Comment: try adding some content to your StackLayout - just a Label or a BoxView or something

Comment: @Jason Hi I add a label but it clips nothing.

Comment: What's your Xamarin.Forms version ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I'm using the latest version.

Comment: Could you show more codes, such as page.xaml, I tested your above code and got a different effect than yours.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Added MainPage.xaml. Take a look pls.

Comment: Maybe your width and height limit it, and the Figures path is out of range, you can try to make the width and height bigger(like 400),you will see its effect.